# How to call Logger service from main.ts in NestJS?

Tags: typescript, logging, nestjs, winston

As you can see, the assembly of the entire application occurs at the time of creation and the call to the asynchronous `NestFactory.create` function. In this regard, I would like to know if there is any way to call your logger inside this function and ask it to catch errors. Now I'm using a regular `console`.

```
const start = async () => {
  try {
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
    const app = NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: true });
    (await app).listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`server started on port ${PORT}`);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

start();
```

But I created the WinstonLoggerModule to log entire Application and services events.

```
@Module({})
export class WinstonLoggerModule {
  static forRoot(): DynamicModule {
    return {
      imports: [
        WinstonModule.forRoot({
          transports: [
            new winston.transports.Console({
              format: winston.format.combine(
                winston.format.timestamp(),
                winston.format.ms(),
                nestWinstonModuleUtilities.format.nestLike('MyApp', {
                  colors: true,
                  prettyPrint: true,
                }),
              ),
            }),
      ],
      module: WinstonLoggerModule,
      providers: [
        { provide: WINSTON_LOGGER_SERVICE, useClass: WinstonLoggerService },
      ],
      exports: [WinstonLoggerModule],
    };
  }
}
```

And the Service as well it's based on Winsto Logger Provider.

```
@Injectable()
export class WinstonLoggerService implements IWinstonLoggerService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(WINSTON_MODULE_PROVIDER) private readonly logger: Logger,
  ) {}

  warn(message): void {
    this.logger.warn(message);
  }

  error(message): void {
    this.logger.error(message);
  }

  debug(message): void {
    this.logger.debug(message);
  }

  info(message): void {
    this.logger.info(message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Dependency Injection like so:

```
const customLogger = app.get(WinstonLoggerService)
app.useLogger(customLogger);

(await app).listen(PORT, () => {
      customLogger.log(`server started on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Refer to [NestJS Documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/logger#dependency-injection)

Comment: get method throws an error sayin ```Property 'get' does not exist on type 'Promise<INestApplication>'.
[0] 
[0] 13         .get(WINSTON_LOGGER_SERVICE, { strict: false })
[0]             ~~~
[0] ```

Comment: Add await in the line where you are defining app. const app = await NextFactory.create. And remove the await from line where you previously awaited the app